# Why doesn't my save system work on Android?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I've created a code which saves progress in game. In Unity it works perfectly - creates savefile in specified folder, but when I import app to Android it doesn't work. Any clue why?

It's my first time working with saving/loading so it might be buggy as heck. Don't be too harsh on me.

```
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

public static class SaveSystem
{
    public static void Save(Helper help)
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/savefile.gut";
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);

        SaveState data = new SaveState(help);

        formatter.Serialize(stream, data);
        stream.Close();
    }

    public static SaveState Load()
    {
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/savefile.gut";
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);

            SaveState data = formatter.Deserialize(stream) as SaveState;
            stream.Close();

            return data;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Save file not found in " + path);
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

```
[System.Serializable]
public class SaveState
{
    public long[] points;
    public int[] level;
    public long[][] cost;
    public long[][] costAdd;

    public SaveState(Helper all)
    {
        points = new long[all.points.Length];
            points = all.points;

        level = new int[all.levelButton.Length];
        cost = new long[all.clickable.Length][];
        costAdd = new long[all.clickable.Length][];

        for (int i = 0; i < all.clickable.Length; i++)
        {
            level[i] = all.clickable[i].level;
            cost[i] = all.levelButton[i].cost;
            costAdd[i] = all.levelButton[i].costAdd;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I've got exactly the same save/load functions except that I use `File.Open()` instead of `FileStream()` and all works even on Android. Can't see anything wrong here :/

Comment: What version of Unity are you using? What version of Android are you targeting? Depending on the combination of versions you might need to override the manifest and add permissions. Here is a forum talking about other settings that also might help: https://forum.unity.com/threads/android-settings-write-access-internal-only-vs-external.425263/

Comment: It's all good now. I've managed to fix it somehow

Comment: And what was wrong, just curious?

Comment: To be honest. I don't know. I was just playing with some unity options and it just started saving. I turn on external access, change app version and changed access to internal again. Weird

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to save it as a JSON Object, its going to help you with that

https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/live-session-quiz-game-2#5c7f8528edbc2a002053b637